# How to log "Connected to X database" with Knex upon start?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm used to console logging that the database is connected upon boot like this:

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose()

let db = new sqlite3.Database("./database.sqlite", sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
  }
  console.log("Connected to the sensor database.")
})

module.exports = db
```

Because I find it helpful just to know it every time I debug something.

But how can I do the same thing if I'm connecting with Knex like this?

```
const db = require("knex")({
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: "./database.sqlite"
})

module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Knex documentation:

> afterCreate callback (rawDriverConnection, done) is called when the pool aquires a new connection from the database server. done(err, connection) callback must be called for knex to be able to decide if the connection is ok or if it should be discarded right away from the pool.

You can find an example here http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client under **afterCreate**

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can easily do, is print something every time you call a knex query. i.e.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const feedbackEntries = await db.getAllFeedback();
        console.log("db has been accessed");
        res.status(200).json(feedbackEntries);    
    } 
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: "Cannot access feedback entries. Please try again"})
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!